# "Internal Server Error" with jQuery.ajax using phoneGap

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, json, cordova

I'm trying to make an ajax request for my PhoneGap application. I'm really new at this stuff, so I don't know what's wrong with my code.
The server needs the facebook token to connect. This is working when I do it via 'curl' on terminal, but when I run it on my android emulator it appears the alert: "ERROR: Internal Server Error"
Localserver is running properly on 10.0.2.2:9000 in the android emulator.

```
function fun(){
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status == 'connected') {
        var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        token = '"'+token+'"';
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http://10.0.2.2:9000/lists/json",
            type: "GET",
            data: {"token": token},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                alert('Success.');
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('ERROR: '+thrownError);
            }
        });
    } else {
    //Not logged in
    }
  });
}
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: What error does it shows in AJAX Response?

Comment: Can you check the token value is correct?

Comment: @KD How can I check that?

Comment: @Ateszki yes, i've check the token value and it seems to be correct.

Comment: If you point your browser to http://10.0.2.2:9000/lists/json?token=validtokenvalue what do you get?

Comment: I get NullPointerException in 
`String token = json.findPath("token").getTextValue();`

Comment: why are you appending quotes to token in this line? token = '"'+token+'"';

Comment: Just to pass it as a String, but it isn't working either without this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnally what I did was appending the token to the url of the server like:

```
function fun(){
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status == 'connected') {
        var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http://10.0.2.2:9000/lists/json?token="+token,
            type: "GET",
            success: function(result) {
                alert('Success.');
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('ERROR: '+thrownError);
            }
        });
    } else {
    //Not logged in
    }
  });
}
```

And it worked :)